# Java IOException: Permission denied on linux while running as owner

Tags: java, linux, io, file-permissions, chmod

I need to create some directories and files and all of them should have permission 0600.
When I Run from NetBeans Debug:
After creating directory when i try to store some files there I get `IOException` with "Permission Denied" message while both directories and files are created with same application at the same time with the same user so I think 0600 (owner read/write) should work.
And When Running Jar file, chmod doesn't work at all!
My code is:

```
if(!Dest.exists()){
   boolean res=dirs.mkdirs();
   if(res){
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod -R 600 '"+dirs.getAbsolutePath()+"'");                
    }
}
File Destination=new File(Dest, source.getName());
documentManager.copyFile(source, Destination);
```

and the copyFile is:

```
public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws FileNotFoundException,IOException {
    if(!destFile.exists()) {
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    finally {
        if(source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if(destination != null) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 600 '"+destFile.getAbsolutePath()+"'");
            destination.close();
        }
    }
}
```

What's the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your stack trace. Probably analyze it yourself. Where the exception is thrown from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory needs to have the executable bit set for you to write files into it. Try chmod +x on the directory.

```
mkdir tmp2323
chmod a-x tmp2323
touch tmp2323/test
touch: cannot touch `tmp2323/test': Permission denied
```

Comment: Thank you very much; now the other problem: why `chmod` doesn't work when I run application from Jar file? (`ls -l` gives "drwxrwxr-x" for all created files and directories!)

Comment: The directory needs the executable bit set to perform any activities on the directory

Answer (score 1):

**For all:**

```
dirs.setWritable(true, false);
```

---

**For only owner:**

```
dirs.setWritable(true, true);
```

**or**

```
dirs.setWritable(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just run `chmod 777 /home` if you wish to create the file in home. Otherwise change `/home` to a different directory. Then your simple code will be able to create the file.